# Is it possible to redirect to different domain retaining the trailing endpoint, from a route?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, webapp2

Is it possible to redirect to a different domain while retaining the trailing endpoint to the other domain. For example, if I hit `http://www.example.com/api/:endpoint`, I would like to be redirected to `http://www.other.com/api/:endpoint`. I realise I could probably do this in the route handler, but ideally I would to put it in it in the routes, from `www.example.com` like so.

```
RedirectRoute(r'/api/<uri:.*>', redirect_to='http://www.other.com/api/:uri')
```

I haven't found anything in the [documentation](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/api/webapp2_extras/routes.html), or from a quick browse of the source for [`webapp2_extras.route`](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2_extras/routes.html#DomainRoute) that indicates how to deal with this.

So basically my question is, can I do this from the route declaration (or whatever it's referred to), without having to build out an entire route handler?

Comment: Did the answer below help you?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation for `webapp2_extras.routes.RedirectRoute` states that the `redirect_to` argument can either be a string or a callable](https://webapp-improved.appspot.com/_modules/webapp2_extras/routes.html#RedirectRoute). A callable will be passed `(handler, *args, **kwargs)`, which you could use to reconstruct a URL using an alternate domain. It doesn't look like you can simply define a string template to do this, however, so you may be stuck writing your own custom Route class.